# Add Quotes to Object Key

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, web-scraping

I'm working on a web scraper to pull basketball stats for a given player during a specific season.  I've come to the point where I place the formatted player stats into an object from a master "game" array, which contains objects corresponding to the statistics for each individual game.  Here's how I'm adding the stats to the `player` object:

```
        player.push({
            date: game[0],
            location: location,
            opp: game[3],
            gameType: game[4],
            result: game[5],
            start: game[6],
            min: game[7],
            fgm: game[8],
            fga: game[9],
            fgp: game[10],
            twoPM: game[11],
            twoPA: game[12],
            twoP: game[13],
            threePM: game[14],
            threePA: game[15],
            threeP: game[16],
            ftm: game[17],
            fta: game[18],
            ftp: game[19],
            orb: game[20],
            drb: game[21],
            ast: game[23],
            stl: game[24],
            blk: game[25],
            to: game[26],
            pf: game[27],
            pts: game[28]
        });
```

This all works as expected and the `console.log` output contains game objects within a final player array.  Here's an excerpt:

```
[
  {
    date: '2019-03-22',
    location: 'neutral',
    opp: 'Ohio State',
    gameType: 'NCAA',
    result: 'L',
    start: '0',
    min: '4',
    fgm: '0',
    fga: '0',
    fgp: '',
    twoPM: '0',
    twoPA: '0',
    twoP: '',
    threePM: '0',
    threePA: '0',
    threeP: '',
    ftm: '0',
    fta: '0',
    ftp: '',
    orb: '0',
    drb: '1',
    ast: '0',
    stl: '0',
    blk: '1',
    to: '0',
    pf: '0',
    pts: '0'
  }
]
```

My problem is the lack of quotes around the object value.  For example, in the above it displays date instead of "date".  Since I'm putting this into a Mongo DB, the quotes around the object keys are (I believe) required for saving a document.  How can I add these quotations around the object keys without giving myself carpal tunnel and doing it manually for each key?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: What you are asking about is just representation. An object can have its keys represented with double quotes (JSON) or single quotes, or without quotes. All these are valid JavaScript notations for the *same* thing. And which format `console` chooses for displaying an object structure is not really bound to tight formatting rules.

Comment: @trincot - Yes, I should've made that more clear in my question.  I understand it really doesn't make a difference from a JS perspective, it's more specifically for this use case where data migration is made easier with quotations around the object keys.

Comment: So your question is how to convert an object to a particular text notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
JSON.stringify(player, null, 2)
```